# Filter model of passive attenuation of headphones

Tags: filter-design, digital-filters, acoustics

It is possible to model passive attenuation of headphones as a Matlab/Python filter ?

For example I would like to find digital filter which will be simulating the way of the passive attentuation of headphones. Particularly I'm interested in [Sennheiser HDA 300](https://en-de.sennheiser.com/audiometers-headphones-high-frequency-testing-closed-dynamic-ear-protector-hda-300).

They gave some table with the data of [frequencies and attentuation in dB](https://assets.sennheiser.com/global-downloads/file/4745/HDA300_References_1018.pdf).

And they told that the measurement was taken according to the ISO 4869-1:1994 norm.
But I'm unable to find the norm.

I have a little experience with acoustics so I have a questions.
How these values in dB should be understand? It is attentuation of sound as I understand but probably I can obtain similar characteristics in Matlab/Python as characteristics of filter?
It is possible to recalculate them into linear scale, for filter developing?
But what reference value should be adopted for this recalculation?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And they told that the measurement was taken according to the ISO 4869-1:1994 norm. But I'm unable to find the norm.

The measurements references IEC 60318 which is available at their webstore.

> How these values in dB should be understand?

The first set of numbers is the sensitivity in Pa/V (Pascal per Volt). That's the ratio of the sound pressure measured at the coupler(s) to the input voltage of the headset. The second set of numbers is the Reference equivalent threshold sound pressure (relative to $20\mu Pa$). This one is more complicated to explain and you should probably stay away from that.

> It is attentuation of sound as I understand but probably I can obtain similar characteristics in Matlab/Python as characteristics of filter?

It's not attenuation. It's the conversion factor between voltage and sound pressure. I can be modelled as a filter in either Matlab or Python, but without a solid mathematical understanding of the fundamentals of DSP and some hands on experience with designing filters for audio, this will be a very steep learning curve.

> It is possible to recalculate them into linear scale, for filter developing?

Absolutely. The linear gain of the transfer function, $G$ is simply

$$G = 10^{L/20}\frac{Pa}{V} $$

where $L$ is the level in dB.

> But what reference value should be adopted for this recalculation?

1 Pa/mV.

Here is a rough outline of probably the easiest way to do it.

1. Generate FFT frequency grid
2. Convert dB to linear gains and populate the grid at the given frequencies
3. Interpolate for the missing frequencies
4. Extrapolate "intelligently" to DC and Nyquist.
5. Add a minimum phase.
6. Do an inverse FFT to get an impulse response
7. Visually inspect: if it's ringy or has echoes, adjust you extrapolation in step 4 and try again

Once the impulse response looks good you have an FIT filter that can you apply to any signal using overlap add or similar methods.